# Find specific text in file and wrap in with other text

Tags: regex, linux, sed, awk

I am looking for the best method to find specific text within a file and wrap other text around it from the Linux command line.

So for example the file may contain the following:

```
This
is
a
test.
anchor-start
text to wrap will is in here
anchor-end
```

So in the above example I want to find the text in between `anchor-start` and `anchor-end` and then wrap that text so that I end up with:

```
This
is
a
test.
anchor-start
wrapping-start
text to wrap will is in here
wrapping-end
anchor-end
```

I should also note that I am looking for a solution whereby if `anchor-start` is immediately followed by `wrapping-start` (i.e. the wrapping has already occurred) then it should not be duplicated.

Comment: have a look at sed and replace `anchor-start` with `anchor-start\nwrapping-start` and `anchor-end` with `wrapping-end\nanchor-end`

Comment: to exclude double wrapping you could use negative lookaround [e.g., in Perl](http://ideone.com/Gyfpl).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might work for you:

```
sed '/anchor-start/,/anchor-end/{/anchor-start/{h;d};H;/anchor-end/{x;/wrapping-start/b;s/\n.*\n/\nwrapping-start&wrapping-end\n/p};d}' file
This
is
a
test.
anchor-start
wrapping-start
text to wrap will is in here
wrapping-end
anchor-end
```

Answer (score 0):

```
pearl.319> cat temp.pl
This 
is a 
test. 
anchor-start
text to wrap will 
is in here 
anchor-end
pearl.320> perl -p -e 's/anchor-start/anchor-start\nwrap-start/g;s/anchor-end/wrap-end\nanchor-end/g' temp.pl
This 
is a 
test. 
anchor-start
wrap-start
text to wrap will 
is in here 
wrap-end
anchor-end
```